# Detecting Tap Events for UILabel inside UITableViewCell using UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uilabel, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a `UITableViewDataSource` with the following

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: OutletDetails.cellIdentifier) as! OutletDetails
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    cell.location = "Some location will be here"
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(locationClicked))
    tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    cell.location.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}
```

where `cell.location` is a `UILabel` object. What I'm trying to do here is to detect tap events on the `UILabel`. I looked all over the Internet and everyone is suggesting this method, however, this code is not working in my case. The method `locationClicked` is not being called at all. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code?

**Edit**
One more thing, is it a good idea to do it this way memory-wise? I mean if we have a long list, then many `UIGestureRecognizer` objects will be generated for each cell. This is because the method will be called a lot while scrolling the items.

Comment: Any luck with my answer? Does it make sense?

Comment: @toddg unfortunately it didn't work for me, I ended up changing the label into a button and format it so that it looks like a label

Comment: Oh I see. You should post your solution and accept it so others can benefit from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add tap gesture to the object and enable its user interaction. Yes you can take button as well.

```
//Adding tap gesture
let cellNameTapped = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:     #selector(nameTapped))
nameLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true// UILabel made available for touch interaction 
nameLabel.addGestureRecognizer(cellNameTapped) //gesture added

//Method called on touch of nameLabel
@objc func nameTapped(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer){
//print(tapGestureRecognizer.view)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're dequeuing a cell, you will need to somehow get a reference to the `UITapGestureRecognizer` and either remove it or reuse it. Otherwise every time you reuse a cell, you will be laying another recognizer onto the one that is already on the cell. If you're subclassing the `UITableViewCell` you can just add the recognizer as a property.

However, using the code you posted I'm suggesting you use a `UIButton` and add a tag so you can get a reference to it later. You can set the bounds of the button equal to the bounds of the label. Try something like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: OutletDetails.cellIdentifier) as! OutletDetails
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    cell.location = "Some location will be here"

    // If we don't already have a button on our cell, create one and set the tag
    if cell.viewWithTag(103) as? UIButton == nil {
        let newButton = UIButton(frame: cell.location.bounds)
        newButton.tag = 103
        newButton.addTarget(target: self, action: #selector(locationClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
}
```